# Remove right bracket from footnote

Tags: pdftex, footnotes

I inserted a footnote in a Latex template, and it suddenly shows up like this

[image: footnote]

all I did was write

```
...as a crossed product\footnote{...}
```

and I really do not know why it is showing just a right bracket there. How do I remove it?

In the .cls file that I am using, there is a section called Footnotes in which this code is included.

```
%-----------%
% Footnotes %
%-----------%

%% The \vfill forces footnotes to the bottom of the page,
%% which is necessary since \raggedbottom is in effect.
%% 30mm is the width of the line.
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@ \vfill
  \hrule width 30mm
  \kern2.6\p@}

\newcommand\xxfntext{%
  \long\def\@makefnmark{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark)}}}
  \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
    \parindent\XxIndent
    \makebox[1.2em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}
}

\xxfntext
```

Comment: some code you have not shown has redefined the footnote formatting, make a small but complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: it is a journal template, so I cannot edit the .cls. Can I re-redefine it, maybe calling it footnoteb?

Comment: you need to give _some_ clue . `\footnote` does not do that by default so you have an error in code you have not shown. Not really possible to help with only that information.

Comment: I tried to dig into the file. I can't see the problem myself, but maybe you guys can. I added the Footnote section

Comment: The line `\long\def\@makefnmark{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark)}}}` contains a `)`

Comment: @henryflower how do I fix it if I cannot edit the cls file? Can I define another command "footnotex" in the .tex file copying that line, and removing the bracket?

Comment: You can copy/paste that piece of code into your preamble replacing `\newcommand` with `\renewcommand` and putting the whole block between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. It works!

Comment: @henryflower I suppose you should post that as the answer:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `\long\def\@makefnmark{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark)}}}` from the `.cls` class that you use contains a `)` which is responsible for your undesired output.
Since you prefer not to change the command definition in the `.cls` class itself, [campa's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559832/remove-right-bracket-from-footnote?noredirect=1#comment1411995_559832) suggestion may be the best alternative: redefining the command in your own document and omit the offending `)`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\xxfntext{%
  \long\def\@makefnmark{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
  \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
    \parindent\XxIndent
    \makebox[1.2em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}
}
\makeatother
```